# async await pass data to partialview mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After reading posts on this site and others I found that you cannot make a partialview async. So I have tried another way, but I get the following error.

TaskTest    Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task

If possible can anyone please help with solving this problem.

```
private async Task<string> GetLocationName(string id)
        {
            var weatherSearchLocation = await Task.Run(()=> _igwccafdf.WeatherLocation(id).FirstOrDefault().WeatherLocation); //Works here, returns data
            return weatherSearchLocation;
        }
```

This is where the error occurs

```
// Task<string> LocationTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(GetLocationName);

            var TaskTest = GetLocationName("london");
```

I have tried a few ways but none seem to work.

Comment: The error is TaskTest Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Comment: That's not an error, that's simply the debugger display of a Task object.  Is there something in that display you're not clear on?